# Get all the email adresses from the page content of a list of urls in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, ajax, email, web-scraping

i would like to get all the get all the email adresses from the page content of a list of urls in javascript.
Here is my attempt, but the code is not executing the javascript on the second page.

```js
var emailList = [];
var urlList= ["http://fr-fr.facebook.com/","http://twitter.com/"]
function getEmails() {

var search_in = document.body.innerHTML;
string_context = search_in.toString();

array_mails = string_context.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
emailList.push(array_mails);

}
for(var i=0;i < urlList.length;i++){
window.location = urlList[i];
getEmails();
}
console.log(emailList);
```

Comment: You're telling the browser to go to a new page and unless that new page has your code it can't execute.

Comment: thank you for the anwser :), but i don't know how to do it then...

Comment: You could create a browser plugin.

Comment: I'm more concerned about what you're going to do with those email addresses once you've harvested them!